# Xamarin iOS Prism (Unity) - Keyboard Extension

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, keyboard

I am trying to build a Xamarin Forms Mobile Application using Prism (Unity) Framework - and add a iOS keyboard extension to the Mobile App.

1. I added the Keyboard Extension Project and added the reference to the iOS application.
2. I added a ViewController in the Keyboard Extension Project (which created an XIB file as well) as below:

   ```
    public partial class ViewController1 : UIViewController
   {
       public ViewController1() : base("ViewController1", null)
       {
       }

       public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
       {
           base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();

           // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
       }

       public override void ViewDidLoad()
       {
           base.ViewDidLoad();

           // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


      }
   ```

   }

When I rebuild and run, and install the keyboard and click on the keyboard icon to switch, the view of the keyboard is not returned.

Here is the code for the App.xaml.cs in main application

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {
        public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer)
        {


        }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainPage?title=Hello%20from%20Xamarin.Forms");
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes()
        {
            Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
            Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage>();
        }
    }
```

I don't know what's missing...?

I can't find any answers on how to bind the view of the Keyboard by code because I am building this using a Windows PC .. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of your keyboard view and assign that object to your view controller View property:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        //bind view to controller
        var viewNib = UINib.FromName("KeyboardView", null);
        View = viewNib.Instantiate(this, null)[0] as UIView;    
    }
```

Replace "KeyboardView" with name of your .xib file